# Shorten jQuery selectors with same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        let li_studio = $('#studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul li:nth-child(2), #studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul li:nth-child(3), #studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul li:nth-child(4)');
        let width = li_studio.outerWidth();

        li_studio.css('height', width);
});
```

How can I save to write the whole `#studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul` over and over again? The only thing that is changing in this selector is the number of the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could build your string beforehand:

```
let selectors = [];
for (const i = 2; i++; i<5) {
  selectors.push(`#studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul li:nth-child(${i})`);
}
let li_studio = $(selectors.join());
```

edit:
you should be able to save the '#studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul' in a jquery element like:

```
const $el = $('#studio_gallery .wpb_image_grid_ul');
```

then use it:

```
let li_studio = $([$el.find('li:nth-child(2)'), $el.find('li:nth-child(3)')])
```

if that's what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you! But that is great for this case. But I would be more interested in a general way of doing this.

Comment: i have edited my answer with an alternative

Comment: Thank you. For now this is working, but I was hoping for something to nest it like I can in less. So if anybody got something that way I would appreciate it.